# Problems embedding certain YouTube Videos into a UIWebView due to lack of eurl parameter

Tags: youtube-api

I am viewing an HTML page in a standard iOS UIWebView. Inside this page I have a standard YouTube embed, something like this:

```
<iframe id="video-play" width="624" height="350" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/hBLf_N-T0vI" allowfullscreen class="hide fade"></iframe>
```

This works fine in all cases on the browser, and in most cases in a UIWebView. But for some videos I get the (I think misleading) message:
"The uploader has not made this video available in your country."

The problem is somewhere in the get_video_info call, and related to the fact that from a UIWebView it seems the eurl paramter is set to "unknown"

So this request works from within a UIWebView:

```
http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?html5=1&video_id=hBLf_N-T0vI&eurl=unknown&ps=native&el=embedded&hl=en_GB
```

This fails, with errorcode 150 and the error message I mentioned above (it will work fine in a browser so use the raw HTTP request below)

```
http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?html5=1&video_id=DldaCQby3j4&eurl=unknown&ps=native&el=embedded&hl=en_GB
```

If I change the eurl=unkown into eurl=http://rubbish.com/ then it works again:

```
http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?html5=1&video_id=DldaCQby3j4&eurl=http://rubbish.com&ps=native&el=embedded&hl=en_GB
```

I've tried to look at the properties of the videos that are failing but can't figure out what is causing the difference between the good ones and the bad ones. I've looked at embed settings, privacy and tracking settings and anything else I can think of.

My other option is to figure out how to add an eurl paramter to the request.

Help!
Jon

If anyone wants the full HTTP requests/response:

BAD REQUEST

```
GET /get_video_info?html5=1&video_id=DldaCQby3j4&eurl=unknown&ps=native&el=embedded&hl=en_GB HTTP/1.1
Host: www.youtube.com
```

BAD RESPONSE

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 23 Nov 2012 15:42:47 GMT
Server: gwiseguy/2.0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Set-Cookie: use_hitbox=d5c5516c3379125f43aa0d495d100d6ddAEAAAAw; path=/; domain=.youtube.com
Set-Cookie: VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=fH943IGDAFc; path=/; domain=.youtube.com; expires=Sun, 21-Jul-2013 15:42:47 GMT
Expires: Tue, 27 Apr 1971 19:44:06 EST
Cache-Control: no-cache
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See //support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=151657&hl=en-US for more info."
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

status=fail&errorcode=150&reason=The+uploader+has+not+made+this+video+available+in+your+country.&storyboard_spec=http%3A%2F%2Fi1.ytimg.com%2Fsb%2FDldaCQby3j4%2Fstoryboard3_L%24L%2F%24N.jpg%7C48%2327%23100%2310%2310%230%23default%23w3GCNZfS0BvXcAQIB1BBnUJRlrY%7C80%2345%23112%2310%2310%232000%23M%24M%23VDmT14lMI4g0sdAxTbIujmEIkkI%7C160%2390%23112%235%235%232000%23M%24M%23c1uKcYcKallke_fsXgoUOkSHnwA&errordetail=0
```

GOOD REQUEST

```
GET /get_video_info?html5=1&video_id=DldaCQby3j4&eurl=http%3A%2F%2Frubbish.com%2F&ps=native&el=embedded&hl=en_GB HTTP/1.1
```

Host: www.youtube.com

GOOD RESPONSE

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 23 Nov 2012 15:42:34 GMT
Server: gwiseguy/2.0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Set-Cookie: use_hitbox=d5c5516c3379125f43aa0d495d100d6ddAEAAAAw; path=/; domain=.youtube.com
Set-Cookie: VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=zG2n4ZwVAdY; path=/; domain=.youtube.com; expires=Sun, 21-Jul-2013 15:42:33 GMT
Expires: Tue, 27 Apr 1971 19:44:06 EST
Cache-Control: no-cache
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See //support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=151657&hl=en-US for more info."
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

account_playback_token .... (chopped for brevity).
```

Answer (score 0):

Could something to do with "claimed" videos. A contact at YouTube got back to us:

> "The videos [that worked] are claimed and the others aren't, so
>   something in the claiming process is causing the issue."